# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) - package "runit"

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, 15.04, dpkg

I was trying to upgrade to ubuntu 15.04 to fix random system crashes on my previous installation but the system crashed during the upgrade, as a result I had to fix it from terminal mode, now I have a 15.04 installation but apparently the dpkg manager has some issues and its preventing other dependent upgrades. Here is the error message:

[image]

Comment: PS:  The random system crashes are still a problem :(  Apparently upgrading hasn't helped at all. I think there is some problem with the GUI, any help is welcome.